# I need some help figuring out syntax for functions in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, function

So I have just made a test solution to play around and figure out how to return a list of values from a function in vb.net. But when I do so I only get heaps of errors. Here is My code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Idk() As Integer = SolveMath()

    End Sub

    Function SolveMath() As Integer
        Dim Num1 As Integer = 23
        Dim Num2 As Integer = 88
        Dim Result1 As Integer = Num1 + Num2
        Dim Result2 As Integer = Num2 - Num1
        Dim ResultsList() As Integer = (Result1, Result2)
        Return ResultsList
    End Function
End Class
```

How do I write the code so that the list Idk() has Result1 And Result2 in it?

Comment: Your `SolveMath` function is declared to return only a single `Integer`.  If you want to return an array, you need to declare it as returning an array (see answer below).  Also, parens are not the correct array initializer, you need to use braces (this change is also in the answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be more useful if you passed numbers to your function. I used 2 NumericUpDown controls to get the numbers.

The result should be visible in the immediate window.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Idk() As Integer = SolveMath(NumericUpDown1.Value, NumericUpDown2.Value)
    For Each i In Idk
        Debug.Print(i.ToString)
    Next
End Sub

Private Function SolveMath(Num1 As Integer, Num2 As Integer) As Integer() 'You are returning an array so add the ()
    Dim Result1 As Integer = Num1 + Num2
    Dim Result2 As Integer = Num2 - Num1
    'You can initialize an array easily by putting comma separated values of the correct type in braces.
    Dim ResultsList() = {Result1, Result2}
    Return ResultsList
End Function
```